# Looking for dynamic e-signature service for a new web application

Tags: html, forms

I have a application that I am working on rolling out and need to do "onboarding".  I need people to sign releases.
I am looking to intergrate a "e-signature" function - not just a simple Accept check box.
I have looked at options like esignlive and adobe esign.
I am not sure if anyone know of a service / tool / JAR/ something that i can incorporate the concept of "signing" an release online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries or tutorials are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow, as the recommendations are subject to personal opinion. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. Questions here should showcase a **specific** coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I did find this js library

https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad